# Full height class doesn't make div the full height

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/LQKfk/2/

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header" class="fullheight">
        <div id="nav">Test</div>
        Nav
    </div>
    <div id="content">
Hello           
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}
#main{
background-color: #3B2F63;
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% top, rgba(84,90,182,0.6) 0%, rgba(84,90,182,0) 75%),-webkit-radial-gradient(right top, #794aa2 0%, rgba(121,74,162,0) 57%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 1000px;
color: #c7c0de;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#header { }
#content{background-color: white;}

.fullheight{
display: block;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}
```

With this code, why isn't the gradient area extending the full height of the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the gradient area a height of 100%, which in turn needs to be relative to the viewport which can be established by setting the same for the `html` and `body` elements.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQKfk/3/)

Add:

```
html,body, #main{
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This approach fails as soon as content is exceeding size of window. Using min-height instead would fix those cases as well.

Comment: `overflow:hidden;` would prevent the element from exceeding 100%, though this is likely not desirable. How would `min-height` help?

Comment: It won't limit the size of `html` and `body` to the height of window but allow to exceed it. It all depends on what is actually desired ...

Answer (score 1):

The full height is basically related to document first. You need to make document full height of window at least to have your divs in document get full height of window.

Achieving this might be tricky *in case of your document is probably containing more content than is fitting in current size of window*, though.

Take the fiddle of SW4 and change

```
 height: 100%;
```

on `html, body` to

```
 min-height: 100%;
```

See this derived fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SGjcc/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
html,body, #id_of_div_you_want_to_make_full_heightwidth_of_window{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body, #main
{
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LQKfk/4/)**

```
#main{
  background-color: #3B2F63;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% top, rgba(84,90,182,0.6) 0%, rgba(84,90,182,0) 75%),-webkit-radial-gradient(right top, #794aa2 0%, rgba(121,74,162,0) 57%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1000px;
  color: #c7c0de;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100%;
}
```